# Equivalent of 'BCC' in Google+ so we can share posts with multiple people, privately?

Tags: google-plus

In Google+ I would like to share a post privately to multiple people, with comments and re-sharing disabled and whoever received this post should not be able to see who else I've shared it with.  Its a bit like the 'blind carbon copy' feature in emails.  Is this possible?

If this is not possible then I think Google are missing a trick here.  I like having lots of small private conversations, rather than big loud shared ones!  I know you can send lots of individual posts, but that is tedious and inefficient.

Answer (score 2):

No, there is no facility within Google+ to share one item with multiple people separately. You'll need to share the same item multiple times.

For what it's worth, there's no facility in Facebook to do that either. In fact, it seems to fly in the face of "social" sharing altogether. If you want to share the same thing to multiple people individually, why not just use email?

Comment: Because sharing via Google+ is a richer experience than the blandness of gmail.  I may want to share something to a group of people and then just add a few more of the personal photographs and share with those who are closer to me, but not each other necessarily.  Moreover, Google+ has the means to share with a single person if we so wish so why not just go the extra mile and make it easier to share to a few people with complete privacy?